# How to generate new QColors that are different

Tags: c++, qt

I wish to have a large array of QColors that many classes will share and index from.

In the past, I've always had the list like such:

```
QColor colours[10] = {QColor("cyan"), QColor("magenta"), QColor("red"),
                      QColor("darkRed"), QColor("darkCyan"), QColor("darkMagenta"),
                      QColor("green"), QColor("darkGreen"), QColor("yellow"),
                      QColor("blue")};
```

However, now I want many more than 10.  How can I create a large list of different QColors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want your list to be dynamic, I would use some sort of QVector instead, wrapped in a Color Manager for example :

```
    class ColorManager
    {
        public:
            ColorManager(size_t iDefaultSize)
            {
                m_colorList.reserve(iDefaultSize);
            }

            void addColor(const QColor& c)
            {
                m_colorList.push_back(c);
            }

            QColor& operator[](int iIndex)
            {
                return m_colorList.at(iIndex);
            }

        private:
            QVector m_colorList;
    };
```

If your colors have to be unique, consider using a QSet, but you loose the [] operator as QSet are ordered structure, and you will have to implement a find in ColorManager, using QSet::find(). It will also be slower.
If it has to be thread safe, you can eventually protect it with QMutex.

Also, I don't know why you need this, but you should have a look at :

`QColorGroup` and / or `QPalette`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a good article on randomly generating colors from sets so that they look good together.

http://devmag.org.za/2012/07/29/how-to-choose-colours-procedurally-algorithms/

Answer (score 2):

```
qsrand(time(0));
QColor(qrand()%255, qrand()%255, qrand()%255)
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee in any way that colors are different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the QColor constructor which takes red, green and blue parameters to create new colors as:

```
QColor colours[10] = {QColor(255,0,0), QColor(0,255,0), QColor(0,0,255),
                  QColor(0,0,0), QColor(255,255,255),
                  QColor(0,128,64)};
```

You can use as many possible combinations of r,g,b to come up with new colors. You can find the Red, Green and Blue parameters for different colors by looking at [Pantone](http://goffgrafix.com/pantone-rgb-100.php) color table and create a nice set of matching colors for your application.